# Using Imagemagick and Paperclip to extend a canvas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm after a very specific conversion result from Imagemagick, taking something like this:

[image]

And converting it into something like this (1140 pixels wide, 12px border around the top, left, and right of the original):

[image]

So far I'm using this code to convert it:

```
convert nike.jpg -colorspace RGB -density 72 -gravity west -background white -extent 1140x104 nike2.jpg
```

But I'm getting this very skewed result:

[image]

Any advice on how to get closer to my goal here? I guess I'm trying to chain Imagemagick commands here to reduce the size to 78px high, add a 12px border, then extend the background on the right to 1140px wide, and I'm not really sure how to chain commands in Imagemagick via Paperclip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved perfectly:

```
convert nike.jpg -colorspace RGB -density 72 -resize 78 -gravity west -bordercolor white -border 12x12 -background white -extent 1140x104 nike3.jpg
```